# grunt build takes too long to complete

Tags: gruntjs

This is what my grunt build tasks execution time looks like. It suddenly increased to 3 hours from 10-20 minutes.

I can see `ngtemplates:dist` and `uglify:generated` taking the major chunk of execution time but 3 hours looks a little off for grunt build process. It's not even that huge an application but barely a skeleton application with limited features in it.

What could be the possible reasons and is it possible to reduce this?

```
Execution Time (2018-02-10 09:16:37 UTC-0)
loading tasks                          421ms  0%
loading grunt-contrib-clean              4ms  0%
clean:dist                              16ms  0%
loading grunt-wiredep                    3ms  0%
wiredep:app                            279ms  0%
wiredep:test                            33ms  0%
loading grunt-usemin                    47ms  0%
useminPrepare:html                      31ms  0%
loading grunt-concurrent                11ms  0%
concurrent:dist                         2.6s  0%
loading grunt-postcss                   68ms  0%
postcss:server                         120ms  0%
postcss:dist                            20ms  0%
loading grunt-...lar-templates          10ms  0%
ngtemplates:dist                    44m 6.1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 24%
loading grunt-contrib-concat           245ms  0%
concat:generated                        1.9s  0%
loading grunt-ng-annotate              588ms  0%
ngAnnotate:dist                        1m 2s  ▇ 1%
loading grunt-contrib-copy              81ms  0%
copy:dist                              204ms  0%
loading grunt-contrib-cssmin           849ms  0%
cssmin:generated                    2m 12.5s  ▇ 1%
loading grunt-contrib-uglify            2.2s  0%
uglify:generated                2h 19m 21.9s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 75%
loading grunt-filerev                  154ms  0%
filerev:dist                           286ms  0%
usemin:html                            164ms  0%
usemin:css                              81ms  0%
usemin:js                              509ms  0%
loading grunt-contrib-htmlmin          119ms  0%
htmlmin:dist                           207ms  0%
swPrecache:production                  399ms  0%
ngconstant:production                  154ms  0%
Total 3h 6m 54.4s
```

Comment: You're answering your own question; you've identified the tasks which are causing the task chain to take an excessive amount of time.  If you want the community's help, you should redefine the scope of your question to an individual task in question and provide more context about the project build.

Answer (score 0):

You might be processing more files than you needed? If it is going to take that long, consider these 2 points to speed up the process.

- Consider using running multiple tasks concurrently.
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-concurrent
- Load all grunt plugins automatically (https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-grunt-tasks) by adding this at the top of the file.

  `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);`